# How is "our" Olivia the correct Olivia?

Tags: fringe

I'm about half way through the fourth season of Fringe, and I have been noticing a bit of contradiction. I would assume J J was leading up to a plot twist, but even the characters appear oblivious to something that to me looks pretty obvious.

There is a running theme that Peter and Olivia are meant to be together. In fact, when Peter enters September's mind, September goes as far as to tell him that he had a son with the "alt" Olivia; and that the "alt" Olivia was the *wrong* Olivia.

But how could this be the case? Peter was brought to our universe only as a direct result of September distracting Walternate when he was working on curing Peter's illness.

September has made it very clear that this was *also* not suppose to happen; he has been trying to "fix the timeline" ever since.

But if Peter was never suppose to be brought to our universe, he would have stayed in his universe with the alternate Olivia.

How is *our* Olivia the right Olivia, when Peter was originally suppose to be in his own universe with *alt* Olivia?

Comment: It's not clear to me that Peter would necessarily have crossed paths with alt Olivia, had he stayed in his birth universe. Note how the only reason alt Olivia had a child with Peter was for her infiltrating our universe. IIRC she was in a relationship (with someone else) in redverse.

Comment: By the way, as you use the "Walternate" moniker, I think "alt Olivia" was dubbed "Bolivia" along the same lines.

Comment: My comment was in response to your statement "But if Peter was never suppose to be brought to our universe, he would have stayed in his universe with the alternate Olivia." I read that as him staying in his universe *and being in a relationship with* the alternate Olivia, but maybe that's not what you meant to say.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper, irregardless, the question remains the same. I'm not interested in speculation about alt Olivia, I'm specifically asking about our Olivia.